# Record video with audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, video, avcaptureoutput

I am going to create app where I am going to record video with audio and then play it.

For this I am using AVCaptureManager in my code.

Here if video is about 10 second, both audio and video playing and it's working fine.

But if I recorded videos more than 10 second, Only video play silently(No sound play on that).

Here is my code.

```
    - (void)startRecording
    {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,           NSUserDomainMask, YES);         
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/GeneralInstruction"];

NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
NSDate *time = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyyhhmmss"];
NSString *timeString = [df stringFromDate:time];
NSString *myUniqueNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", timeString];

NSString *myUniqueName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/%@.mp4",dataPath, myUniqueNames];

[self.fileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myUniqueName] recordingDelegate:self];
    }
```

After that when i complete the recording it comes...

```
    #pragma mark - AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
                   fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
    {
       _isRecording = YES;
    }

      - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
      didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
                   fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
    {//    [self saveRecordedFile:outputFileURL];
_isRecording = NO;

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:error:)]) {
    [self.delegate didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:outputFileURL error:error];
}
```

}

Comment: did you get the answer ? or solution ?